# Asp.net MVC ActionResult how to detect optional parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to detect if an optional parameter has been passed to an ActionResult in my case string `Professional` from the url

`site.com/Account/Register/Professional`
should set the model IsProfessional = true

`site.com/Account/Register/`
should set the model IsProfessional = false

using the following code string professional is always null.

Any idea how to fix it?

```
   public ActionResult Register(string professional)
    {
        // DETECT HERE
        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(professional) && professional.ToLower() == "professional")
        {
            model.IsProfessional = true;
        }
        return View();
    }



  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: what do your routes look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using professional, use id that matches your MapRoute. Try below code:

```
    public ActionResult Register(string id)
    {
        var model = new RegisterViewModel();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) && id.ToLower() == "professional")
        {
            model.IsProfessional = true;
        }
        else
        {
            model.IsProfessional = false;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Or make a new route that defines the `professional` parameter.

Comment: I think using model.IsProfessional = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) && id.ToLower() == "professional"); will be better.